# How to name volume in linux so that I can recognize each volume in filesystem?

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems

I see this folder structure on Ubuntu. It comes by size of each volume. Three volumes are coming with sizes. One volume is for files shared between Ubuntu and Kali and other two are of Kali Linux. 
It is not nice to see it that way and remember the purpose of each volume. 
Can I see any name there?

[image]

After making [this change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392193/117549), volumes are Kali, Kali_Home and Shared are visible, which makes sense than volume size.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tune2fs` to check and create volume names for `extN` filesystems.

**Read current label**

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'volume name'
Filesystem volume name:   root
```

**Set a new label**

```
tune2fs -L vmguest_root /dev/sda1
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'volume name'
Filesystem volume name:   vmguest_root
```

This assumes that whatever GUI you're using to display these volumes actually looks at the filesystem's volume name, of course. (But without knowing what you're using I can't give you a definitive answer.)

Comment: That GUI looks a lot like standard Ubuntu / Unity / Nautilus.

Comment: For FAT filesystems, `mkdosfs` accepts the `-n` *label* option

Comment: Your solution has worked. Except in one shared partition it gave error: 
`# tune2fs -l /dev/sda8 | grep "volume name"
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda8`
I went to 'disks' app and then used "Edit filesystem". There is only one option - Edit filesystem label. 
I checked that the change is working both in Ubuntu and Kali. I changed in Kali and the change is visible in Ubuntu as well. I labeled all volumes except swaps and EFI.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash that sounds like `/dev/sda8` isn't an ext{2,3,4} filesystem. Perhaps it's FAT32 or XFS or NTFS or even something else.

Comment: Yes, it was NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gnome-disks` and for each partition `Edit filesystem` button.

Package name for installation is [`gnome-disk-utility`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gnome-disk-utility).

[image]